# get last visited url using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uri

I visit localhost from my normal html file. The html code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="deal">
<a href="http://localhost:3000">Home</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

my file path is

```
file:///home/selva/Desktop/test.html#deal
```

When I click `Home` link, I need to get `#deal` in to rails project. So I use this method `URI(request.referer).path`

```
require 'uri'
class RefUrlAuthentication < ::Devise::Strategies::Authenticatable
  def valid? 
    puts "PARAMS: #{URI(request.referer).path}"
  end
end
```

And I have tried `request.referer` but no luck.

Here I am getting this error

```
ArgumentError (bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)):
lib/custom_authentication.rb:100:in valid?'
```

this error occur when I use `URI(request.referer).path`

I can't figure out what's wrong in this code. How to I ignore this error and get the url file url. thanks for you time.

Answer (score 1):

`request.referer` can be `nil`, specifically because there is no referer when the user navigates to the site directly by typing in the url manually. You can however default the referer to the empty string:

```
URI(request.referer || '').path
```

Side note: The referer is determined from the HTTP header `HTTP_REFERER`, which is set by the browser. This means that you cannot rely on the data to be correct or even present. Whatever you are trying to accomplish in your authentication strategy, do not base the decision whether a user is authenticated or not on the referer. Someone might be tampering with the value.

Comment: thanks, Now the error is fixed. But How could I take my file path.

Comment: I did not check whether its valid or not, Here I do some other function using that hash value. So I should take the hash value from the file path.

Comment: Maybe your browser does not send the referer header correctly. Thats what I meant when I said one must be careful to rely on the referer. Please check that the header is sent correctly.

Comment: Maybe you could store the value in a session variable instead? This would be the standard way to share data between subsequent requests.